# Is java concurrent package implemented using locks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Conceptually,

```
Mutex

Reader's/Writer lock (Better form of Mutex)

Semaphore

Condition Variable
```

are used as four major synchronization mechanisms, which are purely lock based. Different programming language have different terms/jargon for these 4 mechanisms. POSIX `pthread` package is one such example for such implementation.

First two get implemented using spin lock(Busy-wait).

Last two get implemented using sleep lock.

Lock based synchronisation is expensive in terms of cpu cycles.

But, I learnt that `java.util.concurrent` packages do not use lock(sleep/spin) based mechanism to implement synchronisation.

My question:

What is the mechanism used by java concurrent package to implement synchronization? Because spin lock is cpu intensive and sleep lock is more costlier than spin lock due to frequent context switch.

Comment: It would be best to narrow the question.  However as an opener, Java can make use of monitors, semaphores, await/notify, memory barriers, spin locks, and  cas.  Each of these techniques are used in at least one place within the JDK libraries.  The main technique that I know Java does not use yet is simd, but I believe there is work going on in that area.

Comment: @ChrisK SIMD is actually used inside the JIT compiler intrinsics for `Arrays.fill` and similar operations.

Comment: +1 for the question. the first part is technically (not conceptually) and your bottom question is conceptually. Maybe throw an example from different programing language what exactly do you mean.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik cool, thank you.  I knew that it was on the cards but not that it was actually in.  Do you happen to know when it went in, and whether it ever made it in for for loop optimizations?

Comment: @adhg My whole point is in knowing how one can think of synchronisation without using `spin/sleep` locks? incidentally i came to know that java.util.concurrent package does that. I am not a good java programmer. BTW first part is nothing technical.

Comment: @ChrisK This is my source of information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21525039/1103872 Seems like some boilerplate for-loops are being detected and turned into the intrinsic as well.

Comment: @overexchange 'What is the mechanism used by java concurrent package to implement synchronization?' synchronized is a keyword; not a class or a package, which do you mean when you say 'synchronization'?

Comment: You could always just [look at the java.util.concurrent source code](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/).

Comment: Semaphores and RecursiveLocks and ReadWriteLocks _are_ locks.  Some of the data structures in the .concurrent package (e.g., ConcurrentHashMap and the non-blocking queues) use lock-free algorithms, but any method call that can block until some other thread does something _must_ be using some kind of a lock.  As others have already pointed out, "some kind of lock" can be implemented using native calls through the sun.misc.Unsafe class.

Comment: @overexchange It appears that you are confusing the efficiency of an implementation of synchronization mechanism (by a library or OS), versus the merit of an application programming paradigm that *makes use of* that mechanism.

Comment: Spin locks don't spin forever. All spinlocks have a upper limit, which if exceeded will stop spinning and switch to a different kind of lock, which usually involves sleep, or else they must report a timeout failure.

Comment: To make answering the question more difficult, [the JVM may use spin-locks to implement `synchronized`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689718/what-is-adaptive-spinning-w-r-t-lock-acquisition). So even something that apparently uses "blocking" locks might not actually block very much in practice.

Answer (score 3):

That very much depends on what parts of the java.util.concurrent package you use (and to a lesser degree on the implementation). E.g. the LinkedBlockingQueue as of Java 1.7 uses both ReentrantLocks and Conditions, while e.g. the java.util.concurrent.atomic classes or the CopyOnWrite* classes rely on volatiles + native methods (that insert the appropriate memory barriers).

The actual native implementation of Locks, Semaphores, etc. also varies between architectures and implementations.

Edit: If you really care about performance, you should [measure](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) performance of your specific workload. There are folks far more clever than me like [A. Shipilev](http://shipilev.net) (whose site is a trove of information on this topic) on the JVM team, who do this and care deeply about JVM performance.

Comment: My question is, Is there any class in java concurrent package that performs synchronisation without using lock mechanism?

Comment: @overexchange - why are you asking this?  why does it matter?

Comment: @jtahlborn it matters because lock based synchronisation take more cpu cycles because spin locks take more cpu cycles and sleep lock is 1000 times costlier than spin lock due to context switch.

Comment: @overexchange - where are you getting your performance information and your understanding of the java implementations?

Comment: @i learnt that `java.util.concurrent` package does not implement lock based synchronization. So, I would like to know, How java implements synchronization without using locks. Please correct me, if am wrong. My whole point is, to learn the idea of implementing synchronisation without using locks, if that performs better in cpu cycles.

Comment: @overexchange - my guess is that you are engaging in a severe case of premature optimization.  instead, implement your code correctly.  then do performance testing.  then, if you find a problem, optimize that problem (may be locking, may be something else).  no form of locking or lock-free data structure is _the best_ for every situation.  you need to do _real_ testing to determine which is the best for _your_ situation.

Comment: @overexchange I also support jtahlborns previous comment. It is sound advice.

Answer (score 2):

This question is best answered by looking at the [source code for `java.util.concurrent`](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/). The precise implementation depends on the class you are referring to.

For example, many of the implementations make use of `volatile` data and [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe), which defers e.g. compare-and-swap to native operations. `Semaphore` (via [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java#AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.compareAndSetTail%28java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.Node%2Cjava.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.Node%29)) makes heavy use of this.

You can browse through the other objects there (use the navigation pane on the left of that site) to take a look at the other synchronization objects and how they are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Concurrent collections are not implemented with locks compared to synchronized collections.

I myself had the exact same issue as what is asked, wanted to always understand the details. What helped me ultimately to fully understand what's going on under the hood was to read the following chapter in java concurrency in practice:

5.1 Synchronized collections

5.2 Concurrent collections

The idea is based on doing atomic operations, which basically requires no lock, since they are atomic.

Comment: am sorry, I did not get you, when you say, No.

Comment: To the question ;) Is java concurrent package implemented using locks? No.

Comment: I do not think the referenced document sections are addressing my question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's question and the comment exchanges appear to contain quite a bit of confusion. I will avoid answering the literal questions and instead try to give an overview.

---

**Why does `java.util.concurrent` become today's recommended practice?**

Because it encourages good application coding patterns. The potential performance gain (which may or may not materialize) is a bonus, but even if there is no performance gain, `java.util.concurrent` is still recommended because it helps people write correct code. Code that is fast but is flawed has no value.

**How does `java.util.concurrent` encourage good coding patterns?**

In many ways. I will just list a few.

*(Disclaimer: I come from a C# background and do not have comprehensive knowledge of Java's concurrent package; though a lot of similarities exist between the Java and C# counterparts.)*

**Concurrent data collections simplifies code.**

- Often, we use locking when we need to access and modify a data structure from different threads.
- A typical operation involves:

  - Lock (blocked until succeed),
  - Read and write values,
  - Unlock.
- Concurrent data collections simplify this by rolling all these operations into a single  function call. The result is:

  - Simpler code on the caller's side,
  - Possibly more optimized, because the library implementation can possibly use a different (and more efficient) locking or lock-free mechanism than the JVM object monitor.
  - Avoids a common pitfall of race condition: [Time of check to time of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

**Two broad categories of concurrent data collection classes**

There are two flavors of concurrent data collection classes. They are designed for very different application needs. To benefit from the "good coding patterns", you must know which one to use given each situation.

- Non-blocking concurrent data collections

  - These classes can guarantee a response (returning from a method call) in a deterministic amount of time - whether the operation succeeds or fails. It never deadlocks or wait forever.
- Blocking concurrent data collections

  - These classes make use of JVM and OS synchronization features to link together data operations with thread control.
  - As you have mentioned, they use sleep locks. If a blocking operation on a blocking concurrent data collection is not satisfied immediately, the thread requesting this operation goes into sleep, and will be waken up when the operation is satisfied.

There is also a hybrid: blocking concurrent data collections that allow one to do a quick (non-blocking) check to see if the operation might succeed. This quick check can suffer from the "Time of check to time of use" race condition, but if used correctly it can be useful to some algorithms.

Before the `java.util.concurrent` package becomes available, programmers often had to code their own poor-man's alternatives. Very often, these poor alternatives have hidden bugs.

**Besides data collections?**

`Callable`, `Future`, and `Executor` are very useful for concurrent processing. One could say that these patterns offer something remarkably different from the imperative programming paradigm.

Instead of specifying the exact order of execution of a number of tasks, the application can now:

- `Callable` allows packaging "units of work" with the data that will be worked on,
- `Future` provides a way for different units of work to express their order dependencies - which work unit must be completed ahead of another work unit, etc.

  - In other words, if two different `Callable` instances don't indicate any order dependencies, then they can potentially be executed simultaneously, if the machine is capable of parallel execution.
- `Executor` specifies the policies (constraints) and strategies on how these units of work will be executed.

One big thing which was reportedly missing from the original `java.util.concurrent` is the ability to schedule a new `Callable` upon the successful completion of a `Future` when it is submitted to an `Executor`. There are proposals calling for a `ListenableFuture`.

(In C#, the similar unit-of-work composability is known as [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `Task.WhenAny`. Together they make it possible to express many well-known multi-threading execution patterns  without having to explicitly create and destroy threads with own code.)